# Unable to create MongoDB /data/db directory on macOS Catalina

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos-catalina

I get the following error when I try to create the MongoDB data/db directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db 


mkdir: /data/db: Read-only file system
```

Comment: Execute `mount` and check if `/`, `/data` or `/data/db` is mounted as a read-only filesystem.

Comment: /dev/disk1s5 on / (apfs, local, read-only, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s4 on /private/var/vm (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /System/Volumes/Data/home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)

Comment: `/dev/disk1s5 on / (apfs, local, read-only, journaled)` your root file system is mounted as read-only. Try `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/disk1s5 /`.

Comment: `mount: You must specify a filesystem type with -t.`

Answer (score 5):

The remount didn't work for me (it requires Disabling SIP, which I didn't want to do)
So instead I moved the mongo folder.
You should have the old folder under the 'Relocated items' folder on your desktop
so just copy it wherever you want (I moved it to my user folder)
and then in the terminal go

```
mongod --dbpath /users/<username>/data/db/
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

**Problem because of Read-only file system in mac os catalina**

1. Boot you mac system into recovery mode. 
   (by bootup system with holding CMD+R).
2. Open terminal (Present in "Utilities" in the top left menu).
3. Just run command

   csrutil disable
4. Restart your system and Bootup normally
5. Before doing any activity open terminal and run command.

   sudo mount -uw /

Once this all done you can do write in root location

Answer (score 2):

instead of `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`
i ran `sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db`

this works fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

See the following answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/1458974/macos-switched-root-mongodb-data-folder-to-system-ownership-and-it-cannot-be-cha

You have to create the directory in `/System/Volumes/Data` now.