# Create directory "/dotenv" on MacOs, Read-only file system

Tags: node.js, macos, command-line, directory

I tried to create a directory under root (the directory when I open terminal)

```
sudo mkdir /dotenv
```

But the system says:

> mkdir: /dotenv: Read-only file system

My OS is Catalina 10.15.2

Is there any way to create the dir? I need to run a node.js server locally which requires .env file in the /dotenv dir

Comment: In the terminal, run: `pwd` (print working directory) to see where you are trying to create that folder.

Comment: /Users/chrischen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use `mkdir dotenv` if you are at your profile root (which it appears you are).  That was the only way I could get it to work (I am on Catalina `10.15.3`).

Using `mkdir /dotenv` (notice the `/`) I got the same error as you.

If you really want to, you can disable the read-only file system in Catalina [by following these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59421678/10431732) (which are also listed below).

> ***Problem because of Read-only file system in mac os catalina***
>
> - Boot you mac system into recovery mode. (by bootup system with holding CMD+R).
> - Open terminal (Present in "Utilities" in the top left menu).
> - Just run command
>
>   - `csrutil disable`
> - Restart your system and Bootup normally
> - **Before doing any activity open terminal and run command.**
>
>   - `sudo mount -uw /`
>
> Once this all done you can do write in root location

Answer (score 1):

1. Require the result in command: `csrutil status`
2. If result is enabled, you need to restart machine and press `command + R`, open the terminal in the recovery, so input `csrutil diabled`.
3. Restart, and check the status: `csrutil status`.

Here are two methods:

1. you are root.

   sudo mount -uw /
   so, you could mkdir or touch new file.
2. If you still can't read or write any, you maybe try this:

   cd ~ # cd home directory
   sudo vim /etc/synthetic.conf # create new file if this doesn't exist

In the conf files, add new line

```
dotenv /User/xx/dotenv # Notice: the space between this two strings is tab
```

Restart, and you will find a link named `/dotenv` in the root.